# Error with \RedeclareSectionCommand for submission on ArXiv

Tags: koma-script, arxiv

I am trying to submit my first paper on ArXiv. However, when I try to do so, it comes with an error, saying "Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!"

After searching what is causing this problem, I found that the following lines are the issue.

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
beforeskip=-1sp,
afterskip=1.5\baselineskip]{chapter}
```

These lines are used specifically to shift each chapter title up, so that the whole paper looks nice. If I comment these lines out, submission is accepted, so I know they are the only problem.

Is there any way to submit my paper with these lines? In the worst case scenario, I can comment them out, but my paper looks awful as the result of doing so.

Comment: With older KOMA-Script versions you have to use something like `\renewcommand*\chapterheadstartvskip{}` and `\renewcommand*\chapterheadendvskip{\vspace*{1.5\baselineskip}}`.

Answer (score 1):

[Submit your paper with the appropriate style files included](https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex#wegotem). `\RedeclareSectionCommand` comes from, I assume, KOMA-Script. This command only appeared in version 3.15, which is *relatively* new, at least on the arXiv time scale. So chances are the version of KOMA-Script installed on the arXiv servers simply do not have the newer version(s) of KOMA-Script available, and hence your error.

With this knowledge, what you need to do is to bundle the files you used in your preamble (and anything else they may call on but are not available on the arXiv server) and include them in your upload.